# Use of その 結果 as "as a result'

Tags: word-usage, grammar, use-and-frequency

I would like to know the use of その結果 "as a result"
Is it formal ?
Use in written language ?
Could it be replaced with some other expressions like "それで”　?

> 三ヶ月ダイエットを続けた。**その結果**、５キロやせた。 I continued my diet for three months. As a
>   result, I lost 5 kilos.
>
> 父は、人の何倍も努力した。**その結果**、仕事で成功した。 My father worked so much harder than anyone
>   else. As a result, he has succeeded in his career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その結果 is a commonly used expression and you can use in written/spoken language in any situations. It can be replaced with "それで", but it simply means "and" or "then" in English. In this case, I think "おかげで"(thanks to) is concise and suitable for these sentences like below.

・三ヶ月ダイエットを続けたおかげで、５キロやせた。

・父は人の何倍も努力したおかげで、仕事で成功した。

In negative consequences,  "せいで" should be used instead of "おかげで". Here is an example:

・ダイエットをやめたせいで、５キロ太った。